# How do I customize the margin and label settings with plot_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, cowplot

I would like to have the title not be chopped off and have the axis labels removed from this chart that I generated with plot_grid from cowplot.[image]

Here is my code

```
    data(mtcars)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(cowplot)
 mpg = ggplot() +
 geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(cyl)),data=mtcars) +
 coord_flip()
 am=ggplot() +
 geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(am)),data=mtcars) +
 coord_flip()
 vs=ggplot() +
 geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(vs)),data=mtcars) +
 coord_flip()
 gear = ggplot() +
 geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(gear)),data=mtcars) +
 coord_flip()
 p=plot_grid(mpg,am,vs,gear, labels = "Variables effecting Mileage", label_size = 14, hjust = -0.5,
 + vjust = 0.5)+theme_grey()
p
```

Also, if it would be simpler to create this without cowplot, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `cowplot` only answer. It might be more what you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(gtable)

data(mtcars)

mpg = ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(cyl)),data=mtcars) +
  coord_flip() + labs(x="",y="")
am=ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(am)),data=mtcars) +
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="",y="")
vs=ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(vs)),data=mtcars) +
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="",y="")
gear = ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(gear)),data=mtcars) +
  coord_flip()+ labs(x="",y="")
p=plot_grid(mpg,am,vs,gear) +
  theme_grey() +

# Use annotation text as it is centered at the x,y point
  annotate("text",x=0.5,y=1.04,size=7,label="Variables affecting Mileage") +

# Add some space around the edges  
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")) 


# Suppress tick marks
p=p+scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL)+scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL)

# Have to turn off clipping
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"

# need to draw it with the new clip settings
grid.draw(gt)
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: I had to add library(gtable) in order to call grid.draw and then I was able draw other themes from ggthemes - so that was nice. But your solution did not remove the rug ticks on the x and y axes.

Comment: So is this an okay solution? Not really sure what a "rug tick" is... First time I have heard of them. I just fixed the `library(gtable)`

Comment: We have put a fair amount of work into this upvotes are appreciated.

Comment: Used annotation text as it is centered.

Comment: There might be a better way to get rid of the background grid, but I have to go see a movie now :). Please mark correct if you like it.

Comment: Perhaps simpler to suppress both the tick marks and the text use:

`theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())+theme(axis.text=element_blank())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99029/discussion-between-ftf-and-mike-wise).

Comment: It is after midnight for me now, just got back from seeing Star Wars. Let's try again tomorrow. I am in Timezone GMT+1 (Germany).

Answer (score 2):

would this workout for you?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
a <- ggplot() + geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(cyl)),data=mtcars) + coord_flip()  + theme_grey() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) 
b <- ggplot() + geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(am)),data=mtcars) + coord_flip()  + theme_grey() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
c <- ggplot() + geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(vs)),data=mtcars) +
coord_flip() + theme_grey() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
d <-  ggplot() + geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(gear)),data=mtcars) +
coord_flip() + theme_grey() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) 
grid.arrange(a, b, c, d, ncol=2, top = "Variables effecting Mileage")
```

[image]

Comment: Are you implying that  the only way to change the theme is within the individual plot? Also, can you explain why some of the ggthemes such as theme_economist do not work within the individual plots while others such as theme_wsj do?

Comment: you did not mention theme in your post. some of the themes might not work but you could do it manually anyway. my answer is just an alternative to your question. But if you really want a plot using cowplot, see@Mike Wise answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mike. This does the job.

```
 data(mtcars)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(cowplot)
 library(gtable)
 mpg = ggplot() +
 geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(cyl)),data=mtcars) +
 coord_flip() + labs(x="",y="")
 am=ggplot() +
 geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(am)),data=mtcars) +
 coord_flip()+ labs(x="",y="")
 vs=ggplot() +
 geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(vs)),data=mtcars) +
 coord_flip()+ labs(x="",y="")
 gear = ggplot() +
 geom_boxplot(aes(y = mpg,x = as.factor(gear)),data=mtcars) +
 coord_flip()+ labs(x="",y="")
 p=plot_grid(mpg,am,vs,gear, 
        labels = "Variables effecting Mileage", 
        label_size = 14, hjust = -1.3[![enter image description here][1]][1], vjust = -0.1)+
 theme_grey() +

 # Add some space around the edges  
 theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")) 

 # Suppress tick marks
 p=p+scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL)+scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL)

# Have to turn off clipping
 gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
 gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"

# need to draw it with the new clip settings
 grid.draw(gt)
```

Here is my plot
[image: Solution]

Comment: Oh, that. I would have called it the "background grid". Any chance I can add it to my solution and get the correct? Can give you a tip for your troubles :).

Comment: Please do and FWIW if you have any hints on centering the title with ggplot2_english_first_edition.pdf, that would be cool too. Really appreciate the time that you invested.

Comment: Ok, did it, but didn't get the pdf reference.